# building ionic project for android with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build my ionic project on windows..

when i run cordova build android, it will reach this and then it will stop and end!

> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Lama Tatwany\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk-10

why will it stop? what is the problem exactly?

Running ionic cordova build android result:

> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (57)
>   For more information on which environments are supported please see:
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.5.0
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\Lama Tatwany\Downloads\wesalApp\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Lama Tatwany\Downloads\wesalApp\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Lama Tatwany\Downloads\wesalApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\sass.js:12:19)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post command you used for building app?
You should use : Ionic cordova build android. 
Do you get any error?

Comment: I have used cordova build android, but i will try adding ionic and see

Comment: just posted what i got

Comment: hmm jdk-10 ? try to open android studio manager and check for if you have installed version that match version in your config file of your application.